# Is it possible to put a constraint on a jersey REST method?

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jersey

I would like to do a check to see if we have "turned off" a particular endpoint. Currently it is implemented via a ContainerRequestFilter. But since I can't directly hook into a filter at the controller/resource level (as far as I know) then the best I can do is throw an exception from the filter which is then returned to the client and I would rather the client see a formatted json error response instead of a stack trace.

I implemented the following constraint interface and class:

```
@NotNull
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, PARAMETER})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = MethodNotImplementedImpl.class)
@Documented
public @interface MethodNotImplemented {
    String message() default "{Default message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

public class MethodNotImplementedImpl implements ConstraintValidator<MethodNotImplemented, UriInfo>  {
    public void initialize(MethodNotImplemented constraintAnnotation) {logger.debug("init called");}
    public boolean isValid(UriInfo uriInfo, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintContext) {
        logger.debug("validate called");
        return true;
    }
}
```

I would like to have each rest method then execute the constraint, but the constraint is not firing.

```
@Validated
@Path("/people")
public class PeopleController extends BaseController {
@GET
@Path("/{peopleId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getPeople(@MethodNotImplemented @Context UriInfo uriInfo,
                          @PathParam("peopleId") String peopleId,
                          @DefaultValue("") @QueryParam("fields") String partialResponseFields) {
....
```

Everything compiles and deploys fine, but neither the init or isValid methods are being called when the end point is called. I have other method level constraints set on POJOs in my app and they automatically fire when the method is called. Is what I'm trying to do possible? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using Jersey 1.x or Jersey 2.x?

Comment: At the moment we're using jersey 1.x with plans to move to 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

In Jersey 1.x (RI for JAX-RS 1.1) Bean Validation is not supported so your example wouldn't work. Bean Validation support comes with JAX-RS 2.0 and it is supported in Jersey 2.x almost out-of-the-box (you need to add `jersey-bean-validation` module to your class-path and you can use it). You can take a look at documentation ([Bean Validation Support](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html)) and one of the samples ([bean-validation-webapp](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/bean-validation-webapp)).

In Jersey 1.x you can use concept of [ResourceFilterFactory](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.17/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/ResourceFilterFactory.html) / [ResourceFilter](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.17/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/ResourceFilter.html) which are based on binding filters (`ContainerRequestFilter` / `ContainerResponseFilter`) to particular resource methods (i.e. `getPeople` from your example). An example of such a factory could be [RolesAllowedResourceFilterFactory](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.17/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/container/filter/RolesAllowedResourceFilterFactory.html) which adds request filters to resource methods based on presence of security annotations (i.e. `@RolesAllowed` from package `javax.annotation.security`).